# categorizing the apps in the application launcher

Tags: android, eclipse, launcher

I created an application launcher with the help of http://www.taywils.me/2011/07/05/buildanapplicationlauncherwithandroid.html . I want to categorize my apps in the launcher like education,sports,games etc. How can I do that?

Comment: So you want the app to automatically categorize the app into education, sports, games etc.?

Comment: yes. otherwise if i am able to add a option menu to categorize the app is also good.Is it possible?

Comment: i think this post will help you ..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27962324/android-categorize-installed-applications